# Can't find the Software in the activities

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, updates, software-center

In Ubuntu 18.04 When I click the activities and search for `Software` I do not get any results.

I need to add a software repository as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html.en#canonical-partner). How to find it?

Comment: Which software are you looking for? Do you believe this software is already installed in your computer? Or are you looking for new software to install from the app store?

Comment: I want to install adobe flash player which is not installed in my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible methods are available for this, the GUI or using the terminal:

## GUI:

1. Open "Software & Updates"[image: software & Updates Icon]
   [image: software & updates]
2. go to the "Other Software" tab
3. click "Add.."
4. paste your source there
5. Close Software and Updates and allow sources refresh

(In older versions of ubuntu (including ubuntu 18.04) you could also open this from the top-bar menu of the "Software Center")

## Terminal:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main"
```